# How to Disable Interaction in Sidebar Menu using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I followed the Sidebar Menu Tutorial from AppCoda.com and I'm having an issue with it. I want to disable user interaction when the user is in the menu. Right now, the user is still able to interact with the main screens despite being in the menu.

Link to Screenshot of Problem:
[http://i.imgur.com/1gld2bY.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/1gld2bY.gifv)

Comment: When the front view controller goes to the side, you can add a uiview on there, so that it wont affect anything. If you want to make it darker, you can also do that too. Are you using SWRevealViewController?

Comment: Yes I am, I think that might be the best option for what I want to do.

Comment: Let me post my code if you want to do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your TableViewController i.e. the menu item controller. Essentially this is the view controller that will sit behind your main view.

This also makes your main view go dark, if you don't want that, then set the alpha component to 0.

```
let darkView = UIView()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    darkView.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
    darkView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    darkView.frame = self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.bounds
    self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.addSubview(darkView)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    darkView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SWRevealViewController** for sidebar. Use below code

```
func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {
let tagId = 4207868622

if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Right {
    let lock = self.view.viewWithTag(tagId)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            lock?.alpha = 0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
            lock?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    )
    lock?.removeFromSuperview()
} else if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left {
    let lock = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    lock.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    lock.tag = tagId
    lock.alpha = 0
    lock.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    lock.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.revealViewController(), action: "revealToggle:"))
    self.view.addSubview(lock)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, animations: {
            lock.alpha = 0.333
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**Note**: don't forget to add `self.revealViewController().delegate = self` in your view controller, otherwise the delegate won't be called

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to where I'm supposed to put this

Comment: Also adding `self.revealViewController().delegate = self` gives me an error. It says that I can't assign my view controller to the type SWRevealViewControllerDelegate!

Comment: add self.revealViewController().delegate = self in your viewDidLoad method. Above code in anywhere in your class. It's just like method